# Eclipse не видит org.apache.http.client.HttpClient

Tags: java, eclipse

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с проблемой: Eclipse не видит `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient`. На сам класс `HttpClient` при написании функции не ругается, но запустив отладчик, ругается:

> `Class Dile Editor
> Source not found: The source attachment does not contain the source for the file ClassLoader.class. You can change the source attachment by clicking Change Attached Source below`

Answer (score 1):

Судя по описанию, класс Eclipse, как раз, видит. А вот когда запускаете отладчик, - сообщение, что нет исходного кода библиотеки и предложение приложить его. Так что скачайте исходный код, и когда появится это сообщение, нажмите "Change Attached Source". Далее укажите папку с исходниками.